# customize description environment

Tags: environments, description

I would like to define an environment `induction` which is like the `description` environment. I have in mind that the output of

```
\begin{induction}{A}
\item[a1] Part $a1$ of the induction proof.
\item[a2] Part $a2$ of the induction proof. This one needs a further induction argument over $B$.
\begin{induction}{B}
\item[b1] Part $b1$ of the induction proof.
\end{induction}
\end{induction}
```

should be

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[($A$-induction, $a1$)] Part $a1$ of the induction proof.
\item[($A$-induction, $a2$)] Part $a2$ of the induction proof. This one needs a further induction argument over $B$.
\begin{enumerate}
\item[($B$-induction, $b1$)] Part $b1$ of the induction proof.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I have tried to redefine `\descriptionlabel` but the way I did it I ran into trouble with nested induction environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility, by redefining the way `\descriptionlabel` works at the beginning of every `induction` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{induction}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\bfseries$#1$-induction, $##1$}%
   \begin{description}}
  {\end{description}}
\begin{document}

\begin{induction}{A}
  \item[a1] Part~$a1$ of the induction proof.
  \item[a2] Part~$a2$ of the induction proof. This one needs a further induction argument over~$B$.
  \begin{induction}{B}
    \item[b1] Part~$b1$ of the induction proof.
  \end{induction}
\end{induction}

\end{document}
```

One thing I might change in your usage is to supply `$A$` rather than `A`; that is, remove the automated math-mode insertion of the arguments to `induction` and `\item`.

---

The above solution re-uses the `description` environment within the `induction` environment. If you wish to mix the two, it's best to define `induction` to be completely separate from `description`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*\inductionlabel{}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{induction}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\inductionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\bfseries$#1$-induction, $##1$}%
   \list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
          \let\makelabel\inductionlabel}}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{induction}{A}
  \item[a1] Part~$a1$ of the induction proof.
  \item[a2] Part~$a2$ of the induction proof. This one needs a further induction argument over~$B$.
  \begin{induction}{B}
    \item[b1] Part~$b1$ of the induction proof.
    \begin{description}
      \item[something] something else
    \end{description}
  \end{induction}
\end{induction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed that the nesting problem I had happened actually when I combined `induction` and `description` environments. Does that also occur here? I'm not sure that I will really need to combine these two, but I'd be interested to see how I prevent the renewed description label to carry over to ordinary `description` environments.

Comment: @Egbert: I've updated the answer to include the option of mixing `description` with `induction`.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain what you want and automatic numbering of items within enumerate-like environments, with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{induction}{enumerate}{4}%% up to 4 levels for this new list
\setlist[induction]{wide=0pt, leftmargin =3em}
\setlist[induction, 1]{label=\bfseries\boldmath$A\textup{-induction}${,} $a\arabic* $:}
\setlist[induction, 2]{label=\bfseries\boldmath$B\textup{-induction}${, }$b\arabic* $:}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\begin{induction}%{A}
  \item Part~$a1$ of the induction proof.
  \item Part~$a2$ of the induction proof. This one needs a further induction argument over~$B$.
  \begin{induction}%{B}
    \item Part~$b1$ of the induction proof. This part of the induction proof can be very very long.
  \end{induction}
\end{induction}

\end{document}
```

[image]